# Resize control in Windows Form

Tags: winforms, resize

How I can know when a control, in this case a `DataGridView`, which is included in a Windows Form, size is being resized by the user?. I wish I could tell when its size has changed from a method, or when a user has to resize the windows form. Is this possible?.
I only found `DataGridView.SizeChanged` event.

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish between a resize from the user and a resize from the program?

Comment: Because I keep the size and position of the grid and then to manipulate both parameters.

Comment: But why would this be different if the user resizes vs the program resizing?

Comment: I think I have the solution, you simply handle the event SizeChanged the form that contains the control.

Comment: Is that the grid is used for many purposes and by some methods, is changing in size, so I need to save the initial position and size, but if they can change because the user has resized the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to control the event and there form `SizeChanged` save the position and size of the grid.